# Create a column grouping strings text extracted from a column based on another column in R

Tags: r, regex, string, text

this is my dataset

```
id   text
 1    "red"
 1    "blue"
 2    "light blue"
 2    "red"
 2    "yellow"
 3    "dark green"
```

this is the result I want to obtain:

```
 id  text2
 1   "red, blue"
 2  "light blue, red, yellow"
 3  "dark green"
```

basically I need to put together the text from column 'text' with commas to separate the different elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate`  and `toString`.

```
aggregate(. ~ id, d, toString)
#   id                    text
# 1  1               red, blue
# 2  2 light blue, red, yellow
# 3  3              dark green
```

Note: This won't work with factor columns, i.e. if `is.factor(d$text)` yields `TRUE` you need a slightly different approach. Demonstration:

```
d$text <- as.factor(d$text)  # make 
is.factor(d$text)
#  [1] TRUE
```

Do:

```
aggregate(. ~ id, transform(d, text=as.character(text)), toString)
```

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), text = c("red", 
"blue", "light blue", "red", "yellow", "dark green")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I m not sure how to convert my data frame {that looks like this  id <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3)
 text <- c("red" , "blue", "light blue", "red" , "yellow" , "dark green" )
 data <- cbind.data.frame(id, text) } using the command structure. What is c(NA, 
-6L)? how can I restructure my dataframe so that aggregate words properly? when I run "aggregate" in shows numbers in the text column instead of proper text

Comment: Your column seems to be of class `"factor"`. Please see edit to my answer. You could also use `cbind.data.frame(id, text, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, though, to prevent factors beforehand. (The `structure(.)` thing is just the output of `dput(d)` which is the way we share data here on Stack Overflow, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(text2 = toString(text))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), text = c("red", 
"blue", "light blue", "red", "yellow", "dark green")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```